# what element to be used to display dynamic moving screens in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

what element to be used to display dynamic moving screens in android, what I want to do in my app is to show 3-4 screens to the user moving dynamically based on a predefined time interval of 2-3 seconds.

I am new-bie to android, so wanted to understand how this can be programmed.

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

use viewpager

```
Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data. You supply an implementation of a PagerAdapter to generate the pages that the view shows.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: is it just for moving the tabs horizontally ? or it can be customized to move images on same screen ?

Comment: it can be used for images too